# How to know the content of a container?

Tags: containers

I have container specified in my pipeline as:

```
container 'insilicodb/docker-impute2'
```

It allows me to just run the pipeline without downloading necessary programms. How to see the list of stuff it contains?

Comment: Wrong category.

Comment: Which category am i in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is not on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), so you will need to first know which registry it is being pulled from. Insilicodb is however a [known publisher](https://hub.docker.com/u/insilicodb) on Hub. An example of theirs which lists its Dockerfile is https://hub.docker.com/r/insilicodb/ubuntu/dockerfile.

There is no built-in way to view the Dockerfile of an image you have pulled, it is up to the publisher to provide this. Images don't have to be built from a Dockerfile and may not have one at all. If there is one, it will tell you the steps taken to create that image.

By the way, "without downloading necessary programs" is the *point* of containers. The purpose of them is to be scripted with everything they need to run without you having to install anything.